# Bash function name clash with system binary

Tags: bash, shell-script

In my scripts I have a function called `messages`. I wrote it in Linux Mint, with no problems running it, and when I moved it to a Debian Buster station, the function clashes with `/usr/bin/messages`.

I have a startup script that calls the script `messages`:

startup_script

```
# call to messages script
. messages
```

messages

```
messages() {
  # reformat the arguments and return them
}
```

later on startup_script

```
messages "This is a message"
```

Which throws

```
./startup_script: line 35: .: /usr/bin/messages: cannot execute binary file
messages: could not open mailbox `/path/to/my/script/<string passed to my function>': No such file or directory
```

So I get a bunch of errors related to `/usr/bin/messages` being called instead of my function.

After adding `type messages "This is a message"`, the relevant output is:

```
messages is /usr/bin/messages
```

I have the option of renaming my function¹, but maybe there's a better way to handle this situation.

How do I tell my script to ignore system binaries and use my own functions?

---

<sup>¹ The function is called in several scripts, many times, so it is not the easiest option to just change the name.</sup>

Comment: add `type messages`, before `messages "This is a message"`. What output do you get?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Updated the question, but basically `messages is /usr/bin/messages`.

Comment: At the point you think you're calling your own `messages` function, it has not been defined.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's indeed the calling of the script the problem ". messages" (I'll find out why it doesn't work). Thanks for your time! I have done this "movings" to another OSs and didn't have this problem

Comment: As I have the scripts all in the same folder, I just call them ".  script", to circumvent this I have to put the full path ". /path/script".

Comment: both `help source` and `help .`  shows the same info about the `PATH` is being searched...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how `. file` works:

> If `file` does not contain a <slash>, the shell shall use the search path specified by `PATH` to find the directory containing file.

This behavior is [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).

Your first error is

> ```
> ./startup_script: line 35: .: /usr/bin/messages: cannot execute binary file
> ```

It's similar when you call `. echo`:

```
-bash: .: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file
```

You're trying to source the binary file `/usr/bin/messages`. In effect your file where the function is defined is not sourced at all, the function is not defined in the current script. This means later `messages` still means `/usr/bin/messages`, not the function.

The relevant line should be `. ./messages` or `. /full/path/to/messages` (i.e. path to *your* file, not to the binary).

Comment: Ah, gotcha - the executable takes precedence over the current directory +1

Comment: Brilliant !my internet is slooooww so I couldn't see this before I commented. Thanks!

Comment: It may be useful to note that Bash doesn't strictly enforce the POSIX "dot" builtin spec by default and successfully sources `file` from the current working directory if no `file` in found in `PATH`. (This, combined with `.` not requiring `file` to be executable, is probably a source of confusion, leading people to forget about the `PATH` search part).

Answer (score 1):

## Interpreting error messages

**Look at the line number in the error message**. That way you will know which line the error is on. That was hidden from us, as you showed us a few line from a script containing over 35 lines.

## What file is executed.

When you specify a file with `. file-to-source` or `file-to-run`, the directories listed in the environment variable `$PATH` are searched left to right. The current directory is not in this list, as it can be a security risk, or at least be of confusion. It run a program in the current directory you have to specify that it is in the current directory. e.g. `. ./file-to-source` or `./file-to-run` (There is no need to give full path).

Unixes used to have `.` in the PATH, until it was realised that this was a problem. E.g. put a program called `ls` in the current directory. CMD in Microsoft's Windows still has `.` implicitly in the `PATH`, you can't remove it. It is one of the causes of high mall-ware, on this OS.

## A gotcha

`.` refers to the current working directory not to the directory that the script is in.

To solve that then something like this can be done.

```
(
   cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
   script_dir="$(pwd)"
)
script_dir/other_script
```

Hopefully someone can link to a better solution.