# How can i use hard link to create a shortcut to access the origine from other places?

Tags: shell

I have a project that contains 3 directories (bin, demo and sources).
I have an exe file created by pyinstaller (Which is a GUI script) that contains links to some files in the two other folders(demo and sources).
I simply want to create a shortcut to launch the exe file from its shortcut located in the same folder as demo and sources folder.

I am not sure what I should use symbolic or hard link 
So please tell if i'm wrong

Here the file tree :

```
|
|__bin
|    __exe file
|
|__demo 
|    __[file needed for the exe file ...]
|__sources
|    __......Other files
|
|__{exe file} the shortcut i want to create
```

I tried `ln file.exe ../fileshortcut`  but I clicked it nothing popped up.

Comment: did you use `ls` or `ln`?

Comment: What have you tried? I would use a symlink (easier to update the master file). There can be problems, if the program tries to access files relative to its location, and dose not know that it can be symlinked to. (But you did not ask about that).

Comment: Oh sorry ,it's `ln` . Post updated

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor :Thanks for replaying ,Yeah i tried to run my exe file from parent directory but due to relative links that it containes it (wont't run)

Comment: Put that into the question. It seems that that is what the question is about. Therefore it should be in the question. (at the top)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572278/4778 may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out with a symbolic link:

cd in your demo directory

```
ln -s ../bin/file.exe fileshortcut
```

You should be able to click your link. Also make sure your file.exe is executable.

```
chmod +x file.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ,I tried it already but i got a broken fileshortcut (But when i created it in the same folder as the  original .exe it works correctly (But that isn't what i want))

Comment: Have you tried symlinking with absolute path instead of relative path ?