# How to pass found files repeatedly to be sourced by script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find

I am finding files that do not end with .done like so:

```
find -type f -not -name \*.done -execdir myscript {} \;
```

Now, what I want to do is the following:

-pass each found file to myscript

-source each file in myscript with the source command

-run myscript for each sourced file

Note: that I want to run myscript repeatedly, one time for each file that is found. I do not want to run myscript for multiple files simultaneously. So essentially I am seeking to loop over the found files and source them in myscript. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` command runs `myscript` for every file found, passing the name of the file as the first command line argument to `myscript`.

You want to source the file in `myscript`, so `myscript` should include this in its code:

```
. ./"$1"
```

Notes:

- I assume `myscript` is interpreted by a shell.
- You mentioned `source` but `.` is more portable.
- I used `./"$1"` because you used `-execdir`. [It seems](https://superuser.com/q/1480324/432690) some implementations of `find` don't include `./` in the string substituted for `{}` after `-execdir`. If this was the case, then [this mishap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572245/108618) could happen. Adding an explicit `./` prevents this.